# SQL Teradata Date Case When Then Loses Date Format

Tags: sql, teradata

When I perform the following statement, the date formatting is lost in epc.LAST_LICPLT_REPRINT_DT:

```
 ,CASE When epc.LAST_LICPLT_REPRNT_DT is null Then ''
 ELSE '' + epc.LAST_LICPLT_REPRNT_DT 
 END as LAST_LICPLT_REPRNT_DT
```

I've tried to use

```
  cast(epc.LAST_LICPLT_REPRNT_DT as date)
```

and

```
 cast(epc.LAST_LICPLT_REPRNT_DT as DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')
```

nether work.

Comment: This does not make sense if the field is a date: `'' + epc.LAST_LICPLT_REPRNT_DT`. You need to choose between returning a string or returning a date.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  All I can see is that if `epc.LAST_LICPLT_REPRNT_DT` is null, you're replacing it with an empty string, otherwise showing the column. Trading null for an empty string doesn't seem very productive to me.

Comment: Just get rid of the "?" representing null in the data

Comment: Oh, that's just an option in SQL Assistant.  On my version, it's in `Tools>Options>Data Format`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(epc.LAST_LICPLT_RPRNT_DT AS VARCHAR(10)), '') --Return Empty String If Date Null
     , COALESCE(epc.LAST_LICPLT_RPRNT_DT, DATE '9999-12-31') -- Return High Date if Date is Null
  FROM {MyDB}.{MyTable}
 WHERE epc.LAST_LICPLT_RPRNT_DT IS NULL;
```